# when I try to establish connection to the database ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

Tags: python, pip, conda, mysql-connector-python

whenever I try to run `pip install mysql-connector` ,it stores in anaconda library and when I try to make a connection to the data base it throws a message module not found. please help. I manually copy pasted the folder into the python library but no success.

I have tried all possible combination of:

```
pip install mysql-connector
pip install mysql-connector-python
pip install mysql-connector-python-rf
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It appears you tried to format some of your question as code using three apostrophes ''', but you need to use the backticks ` On a US-English keyboard, the will be the top-left key, just under the esc, sharing a space with ~.

Comment: If you are using anaconda, you might either be installing it to a virtual environment and running your code on the real environment, or vise versa. You could also be installing to python2 and running with python3. If so, make sure you run `activate /path/to/env` to select the right environment before running your code.

Comment: i want to use vs code for all my operations, coding etc. i rarely open anaconda. i believe while installing anaconda i added path so now whenever i try to add something it is added to anaconda site-packages like i updated pip it was stored in
```c:\users\91971\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)```
same ways while installing the connectors they were stored over here... is it the reason i am facing error Module not found whenever i try to create a database from vscode. i added some of the extensions to vscode and i am able to connect to database. i am very new and need elaborate ans.

Comment: To install using the regular pip, you just need to find the right instance. You may want to modify your PATH so that it comes before the anaconda packages. If you are on windows, it will be somewhere like `c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip`. You can also just run the program with a fully qualified path. Then, in VS code, you can [select your Python interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) so it will use the environment with the installed packages.

Comment: Be careful not to install things in the base/root environment! Create a new environment for each project/application.

Answer (score 0):

In my case **pip install mysql-connector-python** works

make sure you update your pip

Comment: i tried doing so it was successfully updated. still
PS D:\New folder> & C:/Users/91971/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe "d:/New folder/test_mysql.py"   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/New folder/test_mysql.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
may be its a mismatch of where the packages are stored and from where it is trying to reach out.packages are stored in
c:\users\91971\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
if it is the case what might be the solution.. pls elaborate i am very new to such techies

Comment: try to uninstall mysql-connector using pip and install again may be there is mismatch with the filepath

Answer (score 0):

Actually this module, is not available publically, that's why we're getting these error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).